# How to have Yii2.0 CheckboxList items as checked as the form loads?

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to use a Activeform checkboxlist widget in YII 2.0 Framework

in my case, i have an array called "list" which has the names of languages which will be rendered out as checkboxlist, now i am able to do that, but i want the check boxes to be checked as the form loads.

```
$list = [0 => 'PHP', 1 => 'MySQL', 2 => 'Javascript'];
$list2 = [0,2];
```

using the following line, i am able to acheive what i want using HTML helper classes :

```
<?= Html::checkboxList('CuisineId',$list2,$list); ?>
```

but i want to be able to do this using the Activeform Widget CheckboxList, which as per [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkboxList%28%29-detail) is to be used in the following way :

> static checkboxList( $items, $options = [] )

So in my case, i have figured how to pass the parameter for $items, which is in the following way:

```
<?= $form->field($record, 'CuisineId')->checkboxlist($list);?>
```

But now i do not know how to pass the parameters that will allow the checkboxes to be checked.

Comment: Set the attribute's value to 'PHP'?

Comment: No, in Yii2, using the checkboxlist, i am able to generate a form with 3 checkboxes, with the label "PHP", "MySQL" and "Javascript" , i want to be able to have the checkbox for "PHP", already checked as the form loads.

Comment: Is the value already set/coming from the model?

Comment: This works for me: \yii\helpers\BaseHtml::checkboxList('CuisineId', $list2, $list);

Answer (score 5):

Okay i got the solution from [yiiframework forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53418-checkboxlist-options/) itself.

The solution was just to add the following line of code and it worked! :

```
$record->CuisineId = $list2;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solve**
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnzfo.jpg)

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK2TF.png)

Controller

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->INDEXES =ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->publicationIndexes, 'INDEXES_ID');

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {$model->save();}
```

View (_form)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'INDEXES')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map(Indexes::find()->all(), 'ID', 'NAME')) ?>
```