# How to create yii2 inline checkbox list

Tags: php, html, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

I have described my problem on [yii2 forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60596-how-to-create-inline-checkbox-with-checkboxlist/), but no one helped me, most likely because no one knows the answer.

Here is the short description here.

I would like to make this:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="ASD">Option 1</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="DSA">Option 2</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="REW">Option 3</label>
```

but with yii2 checkboxList Html helper.

This is my simplified array of checkbox values

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'country')->checkboxList(['FR'=>'France', 'DE'=>'Germany']) ?>
```

I need to insert the `class="checkbox-inline"` into the label tags of each checkbox generated by this yii2 helper method but I can not figure out how to do it.

I was following these guides: [checkboxList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#checkboxList%28%29-detail) and checkbox one ( I can't post more than 2 links because I am new here ) but they are not helpful to me, I just do not understand what I have to do. Everything I tried just failed.

Can someone help me please, I am trying for 3 days now ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should simply use :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'country')->inline(true)->checkboxList(['FR'=>'France', 'DE'=>'Germany']) ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#inline()-detail

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that those options exists at all.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to mark some fields as checked by default ? Let's say that I want to mark FR (France) as checked when form loads.

Comment: @black-room-boy As for checking something by default (when form loads), it depends on how you render your checkBoxList? Whether you do this by a simple HTML helper classes or as an ActiveField, being part of ActiveForm. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23087963/1469208) and following answer should help you, as it discusses both approaches to this problem.

Comment: How can we save them it database and show them checked in view