# Pre-Checked CheckboxList in Yii2

Tags: yii2, checkboxlist

Here am having Table `mail_for`, in this table i have data as

```
id email_for
1  Hr
2  Tpa
3  Insurer
4  Client
5  no_reciptents
```

so i have maked a checkbox list for these data using this code

```
<?php
     $mail_for = ArrayHelper::map(MailFor::find()->all(),'id','email_for');
     echo  $form->field($model, 'email_for')->checkboxList($mail_for, array('checked'=>'checked')); 
?>
```

So, what i need to `pre checked` checkboxList for the `id 5` (no_reciptents)

Comment: refer this question for hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087963/how-to-have-yii2-0-checkboxlist-items-as-checked-as-the-form-loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the value to be prechecked like below before the email_for field.

```
$model->email_for = $ValueToBePrechecked;
```